# Undefined offset error while printing values from db in php

Tags: php, warnings, offset

Undefined offset error occurs while printing values of `mysqli_fetch_array()` using `for` loop:

Code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($serverid,$useid,$passwordid,$dbid);<br>
$fieldcheck= "Select * from userregistrationform";<br>
$execfield=mysqli_query($con,$fieldcheck);<br>
if(mysqli_num_rows($execfield)>0) {
    $idcheck= "Select ChangeID from userregistrationform";
    $execq0=mysqli_query($con,$idcheck);
    $idcmp=mysqli_fetch_array($execq0);
    $idlength=count($idcmp);
    echo $idlength;
    for($x=0;$x < $idlength;$x++) {
        echo $idcmp[$x];
    }
```

NOTE:

1. ChangeID is a column in my database.
2. The code worksfine when i use

   ```
   while($idcmp=mysqli_fetch_array($execq0)) {
       echo $idcmp['ChangeID'];
   }
   ```

But it would be helpful why the error occurs if i use for loop.

Comment: `print_r($idcmp);` What do you see?

Comment: It seems the `mysql_fetch_array` returns a single array for the row with _both_ key-based and index-based items. So `$idlength` is likely 2 (for both types in the array) but there is only a `$idcmp[0]` available.

Answer (score 1):

When you print your `$idcmp` you will see something like:

```
array('ChangeID' => 100)
```

See, the key in array is `ChangeID`.

When you do

```
for($x=0;$x < $idlength;$x++) {
    echo $idcmp[$x];
}
```

you try to access key with value `0`. But there's no key `0` in `$idcmp`. That's why you get a `offset` error.

Comment: Thank you for your response,<br>Kindly clarify what need to be corrected in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The default result type parameter for `mysqli_fetch_array()` is `MYSQLI_BOTH`, which means you get the result as a numeric array and an associative array (combined in a single array), if you do not pass any specific arguments.

Try changing this:

```
$idcmp=mysqli_fetch_array($execq0);
```

into this:

```
$idcmp=mysqli_fetch_array($execq0,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After making the change, offset error doesn't occur but only one value of column "ChangeID" is printed but not printing all the values

Comment: What is the echoed $idlength?

Comment: It is to print the count of values of "ChangeID" column in database

Comment: No, I mean, what does it print now?